# is AWS CloudFormation supports Cloudformer feature to create template from existing infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to create a CloudFormation YAML template from the existing resources and faces some issues. However, I don't see this coming when creating the stack from the AWS dashboard.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBJ7f.png)

Apparently, it supposes to be in the tools section which they deleted the template and created a new way for the template. Do I miss anything here?

Answer (score 0):

`CloudFormer` is deprecated and **no longer maintained** by AWS.  Instead, please have a look at a look at [Former2](https://former2.com/) which seems be de-facto go-to tool to use now in place of `CloudFormer`:

> Former2 allows you to **generate Infrastructure-as-Code outputs** from your existing resources within your AWS account. By making the relevant calls using the AWS JavaScript SDK, Former2 will scan across your infrastructure and present you with the list of resources for you to choose which to generate outputs for.